# Creating a generic<string> to work with a list

Tags: c#, list, generics

I am trying to create my own Settings for a applicaiton (Properties.Settings does not work the way i need it) i have created tis:

Generic class setup:

```
public abstract class AppSettingsPropertie
{ }

class AppSettingsPropertie<T> : AppSettingsPropertie where T : struct
{
    public AppSettingsPropertie(string name, T value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

where i need it:

```
List<AppSettingsPropertie> Properties;
Properties = new List<AppSettingsPropertie>();
Properties.Add(new AppSettingsPropertie<string>("hello", "test"));
```

VS tells me it cant use a string becouse it does not get a value and is null

Comment: you have constraing `where T : struct`, but _string_ - not a struct, so what behaviour you expect? :-)

Comment: Remove the `where T : struct` restriction and the code will compile.

Comment: As a side note: it should be spelled `AppSettingsProperty`.

Comment: You should explain why `Properties.Settings` does not work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the where T : struct restriction and the code will compile. – pasty
and it works